# Computing modular square roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to be able to determine when there exist square roots, in this case,$\pmod {67}$ and when square roots exist, how to compute them.

$x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {67}$ and $x^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {67}$.

For the first one, I checked numbers squared up to $30$ and found no answers. For the second, I found that $26^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {67}$.

But this method is very time consuming and I can't say that $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {67}$ has no solutions, only that it has no solutions between $1$ and $30$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining whether square roots exist modulo a prime and finding them
is a big topic in elementary number theory. For example, there is
a theorem that $x^2\equiv2\pmod p$ is soluble for a prime $p$ if and only
if $p\equiv\pm1\pmod 8$. Beyond this you need to study [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). Once you have quadratic reciprocity it is very
quick to determine if you have a solution.

Finding a solution is a bit more difficult. Actually $67\equiv-1\pmod 4$
is an easier case. Suppose $p\equiv-1\pmod 4$. Then if $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ is soluble then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv1\pmod p$ (this is *Euler's Criterion*). But in this case $(p+1)/2$ is even and we can take
$x=a^{(p+1)/4}$ for then
$$x^2=a^{(p+1)/2}=aa^{(p-1)/2}\equiv a\pmod p.$$
For $p\equiv1\pmod 4$ one needs more sophisticated approaches
like the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

For square roots modulo a non-prime $n$ one can use the Chinese
Remainder Theorem, provided one can factor $n$ into primes.