# Find the number $m$ such that $m^2 + 1$ is divisible by $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the number $m$ such that $m^2 + 1$ is divisible by $x$ for $x = 474993$

So, I think it will be $m^2+1 \equiv 0$ (mod $474993$), I have no clue how to solve this, any hints would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing modular square roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444039/computing-modular-square-roots)

Comment: Using $p$ to denote the modulus is misleading, because $474993 = 3^2 \cdot 52777$ is not actually prime...

Comment: $p=3^2 \cdot 89 \cdot 593$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What is the context? A course in elementary number theory? Is it exam time???

Comment: and $m^2+1\equiv0\pmod{3^2}$ has no solutions

Comment: @HansEngler I'm practicing exercises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* There are no solutions to the given equation.

> Observe that $474993=3^2\cdot89\cdot593$. Thus, $m^2+1\equiv 0\bmod 474993\implies m^2\equiv-1\bmod 3$ . Yet it is well known that this is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a question, how can you factoring a large number? Like you did $474993 = 3^2\cdot89\cdot593$

Comment: There are tools such as [this](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/prime-factors.php) online to factor large numbers. In your case, however, it is easy to see that the number is divisible by $9$ because the sum of its digits is divisible by $9$. So the use of $\bmod 3$ to determine the lack of solutions follows without needing to fully factor the number.

Comment: Exactly! In this case, it was enough to check that $474993\equiv0\bmod3\iff 4+7+4+9+9+3\equiv 0\bmod 3$